# How to use getDataInBackground to transform an entire PFFile array into a UIImage one

Tags: ios, swift

I am loading PFFile (images) into a table view and I would like to know how to `getDataInBackground` for an array, without wasting anything (memory or something, I don't know). That means literally transforming a PFFile array into a UIImage array in an efficient way.

I tried this:

```
   self.UIImagesArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

   for i in 0..<self.imagesArray.count { // imagesArray is a PFFile array     
        imagesArray[i].getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {      
                if let imageData = data {
                    if let imageToDisplay = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        self.UIImagesArray.append(imageToDisplay)
                    }
                }
            }

            if self.imagesArray.count == self.UIImagesArray.count {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
```

I believe I couldn't explain the results to you, because I feel like my UIImages array is randomly filled, so that every time I actualize my table view, the picture for each cell is always/most of the time different.

I would be glad to have some help.

Answer (score 0):

The order you're seeing depends on the time it takes each image to download. What you need to do is to store the received images along with their index, and then once all are assembled, convert them back into an array in the correct order:

```
self.UIImagesArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

for i in 0 .. <self.imagesArray.count { // imagesArray is a PFFile array
    var imgDict = [Int: UIImage]()
    imagesArray[i].getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let imageData = data {
                if let imageToDisplay = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    imgDict[i] = imageToDisplay
                }
            }
        }

        if self.imgDict.count == self.imagesArray.count {
            self.UIImagesArray = imgDict.keys.sorted().compactMap { imgDict[$0] }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: ty for the answer, but do you know how I could call correctly this function in `tableView cellForRowAt indexPath`? because I get the error 'index out of range'

Comment: You should not do that, since the function itself calls `reloadData`.